# Table with percentage width does resize appropriately in IE8

Tags: html, html-table, internet-explorer-8

- I have a table element contained in a div and the table is set a width of 100%.
- The div element is reduced in width whenever the browser width reduces.
- In Chrome, Safari, Firefox and IE7 when the div get resized, the table also is resized.
- But in IE8, though, the table remains without being resized and overflows the container div

Following is the structure I am dealing with

```
    <div style="width:500px">
       <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="100%">
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td valign="top">
                <div>My table column contents</div>
              </td>
              <td valign="top">
                <div>My table second column contents</div>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
       </table>
    </div>
```

Answer (score -2):

You have the table wrapped in a div with a defined width. Just define the width of the table too.

Comment: This is not at all an answer to the issue being discussed. This is actually a bug in IE 8. Others have pointed it out, for example: http://srikanthgade.blogspot.com/2010/09/ie8-standards-table-layout-fixed.html

Comment: Thanks for the correction. I originally misread the post because Mandai had posted the div with a set width. I didn't understand that the div was resizing at some point. Thanks for the link.